# google doc addon how to add textbox value to google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, add-on

I am not a programmer.

Can someone help me with the following.
I am following this guide on how to make a google doc add-on.

[http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~vahid/usefulstuff/gdoc_addon/](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Evahid/usefulstuff/gdoc_addon/)

I have gotten this to work.

What I want to achieve is,

The user types in the google doc as normal and adds words typed in text box (in the sidebar) with some formatting added by app-script, where the cursor is.

for example

//on button click insert text in gdoc where the cursor is

"formatting1" + textbox1-text + "formating2" + textbox2-text + "formating3"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Textbox is an image right, so you get all the images and check which one is a textbox image and look for the text inside it by perhaps using a get text method.

```
 DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getImages().forEach((elem) => {//your logic});
```